# Render a functional component after fetching data from a POST API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to re-render my component after the data fetched from my API. I used hooks to handle that. but it does not working. actually my component renders for the first time, not after fetching data!

---

I have an external function. By this function, I can give a province name to that and then receive a list of the cities which they are in that province. my function is like below:

```
const axios = require('axios');
export default async function getCities(state) {
    let res = [], err;
    try {
        await axios.post('someUrl', {
            ProvinceUser: state,
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++)
                    res.push(response.data[i].CityUser);
            }
        }).catch(function (error) {
            err = error;
        });
    } catch (error) {
        err = error;
    }
    return {
        response: res,
        error: err
    }
}
```

---

I'm using the above function in my component like below:

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import getCities from "../functions/getCities";
import RadioList from "./RadioList";

export default function ListOfStates(props) {
    let labels = [],
        cities = [];
    useEffect(() => {
        getCities(props.cityState).then((array) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < array.response.length; i++)
                cities.push(array.response[i]);
            labels = cities;
        });
    }, []);
    return (<>
        {labels.map((labels, index) =>
            <RadioList active={(labels === props.active)} key={index} label={labels}/>)}
    </>);
}
```

---

### It's good to say:

1. I used `console.log(labels)` in `useEffect`. and everything is okay
   with `labels` array. just the component should be updated.
2. I used `labels` array for the deps in `useEffect`. but it does not
   worked.

So, which parts are going wrong?

Comment: Simply updating the value of a variable won't trigger a render, however if you declare your `labels` as a state array using the `useState()` hook updating it will.

Comment: I used states to handle it. But i couldn't put the data in a state. for arrays we use `array.push(something)`. So, could you plz post an answer and tell me how can i do it with a state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply updating the value of a variable won't trigger a render, however if you declare your labels as a state array using the `useState()` hook updating it will.

*Note:* Using index as a key is an anti-pattern which will only lead to headaches later, choose a unique identifier for each element to use as key instead.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import getCities from "../functions/getCities";
import RadioList from "./RadioList";

export default function ListOfStates(props) {
  const [labels, setLabels] = useState([]);
  const cities = [];

  useEffect(() => {
    getCities(props.cityState).then((array) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < array.response.length; i++) {
        cities.push(array.response[i]);
      }
      setLabels([...cities]);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {labels.length && labels.map((labels, index) =>
        <RadioList active={(labels === props.active)} key={labels.id} label={labels} />)}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi again, i tried to use `redux` instead of pure react states. it was not working. I post my codes in another answer on this thread. could you plz read them and help me?

Comment: I think you would get better responses if you posted it as a separate question, and also it is slightly off topic to post a question as an answer.