# Push an array elements in a redux state returns `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I wanna use *redux* to do [@pilchard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13762301/pilchard)'s solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65865139/14174769). It was not working in redux. where is going wrong with my codes?

### action/index.js:

```
export const setCities = (city) => {
    console.log(city)
    return {
        type: GET_CITIES_BY_SPECIAL_STATE,
        payload: city
    }
}
```

### reducers/mainReducer.js

```
import {
    GET_CITIES_BY_SPECIAL_STATE
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    cities: []
}
const mainReducers = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_CITIES_BY_SPECIAL_STATE:
            return {...state, cities: state.cities.concat(action.payload)}
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export default mainReducers;
```

### reducers/index.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import mainReducers from "../reducers/main";
const reducers = combineReducers({
    setCitiesReducer: mainReducers
});
export default reducers;
```

### And this is how i use them:

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import getCities from "../functions/getCities";
import RadioList from "./RadioList";
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {setCities} from '../redux/actions'

function ListOfStates(props) {
    let labels = [],
        cities = [];
    useEffect(() => {
       getCities(props.cityState).then((array) => {
           for (let i = 0; i < array.response.length; i++)
               cities.push(array.response[i]);
           props.setCities([...cities]);
       });
    }, []);
    return (<>
        {
            props.city.map((labels, index) =>
                <RadioList active={(labels === props.active)} key={index} label={labels}/>)
        }
    </>);
}

const mapStatesToProps = state => {
    return {
        city: state.setCitiesReducer.city,
    }
}
export default connect(mapStatesToProps, {setCities})(ListOfStates);
```

### The error is:

*TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined*

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function ListOfStates(props) {
    let labels = [],
        cities = [];
    useEffect(() => {
       getCities(props.cityState).then((array) => {
           for (let i = 0; i < array.response.length; i++)
               cities.push(array.response[i]);
           props.setCities([...cities]);
       });
    }, []);
    return (<>
        {
            props.city.map((labels, index) =>
                <RadioList active={(labels === props.active)} key={index} label={labels}/>)
        }
    </>);
}

const mapStatesToProps = state => {
    return {
        city: state.setCitiesReducer.cities,
    }
}
export default connect(mapStatesToProps, {setCities})(ListOfStates);
```

Answer (score 0):

*[@jzProg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15064882/jzprog)'s answer helps me to improve the most correct answer.*

```
function ListOfStates(props) {
    let labels = [],
        cities = [];
    useEffect(() => {
       getCities(props.cityState).then((array) => {
           for (let i = 0; i < array.response.length; i++)
               cities.push(array.response[i]);
           props.setCities([...cities]);
       });
    }, []);
    return (<>
    {(props.city['0'] === undefined) ? (<p>Loading...</p>) : (
        props.city['0'].map((labels, index) =>
            <RadioList active={(labels === props.active)} key={index} label={labels}/>)
    )}
</>);
}

const mapStatesToProps = state => {
    return {
        city: state.setCitiesReducer.cities,
    }
}
export default connect(mapStatesToProps, {setCities})(ListOfStates);
```